# How to deal with Visual Studio's warning C6011 after using realloc?

Tags: c, visual-studio, malloc, compiler-warnings, realloc

I am following Microsoft's guidelines on how to work around this warning but it doesn't seem to work.

I add all the checks but, when I copy the 'expanded' pointer `tmp` to `ptr` and try to use it, I get another warning:

> Warning C6200   Index '1' is out of valid index range '0' to '0' for
> non-stack buffer 'ptr'

```c
void main(void)
{
    int* ptr, * tmp;//I start with two pointers
    ptr = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    ptr[0] = 10;
    if (ptr != NULL)//make sure ptr is not null.
    {
        tmp = (int*)realloc(ptr, 5 * sizeof(int));//expand tmp up to 5
        if (tmp != NULL)//make sure it went well.
        {
            ptr = tmp;
            ptr[1] = 20;
/*
Warning C6200   Index '1' is out of valid index range '0' to '0' for non-stack buffer 'ptr'.    
 */
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you include `stdlib.h`?

Comment: @AndrésSanchez What compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: OT: `int main(void)`

Comment: @david-ranieri yes <stdlib.h> is properly included.

Comment: It seems like the diagnostic message is too dumb to recognize realloc. Though naturally `ptr[0] = 10; if (ptr != NULL)` doesn't make any sense. Does it make a difference if you fix that bug?

Comment: @Lundin Addressing the C6011 issue does *not* resolve the C6200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C6011 warning is valid and can be addressed by moving the `ptr[0] = 10;` line to *after* you have checked that the initial `ptr` value returned by `malloc` is not `NULL`.

However, the C6200 warning is just plain wrong, as discussed, for example, [in this blog](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/analyze-for-visual-studiothe-ugly-part-1/).

There are a couple of 'tricks' you can use to silence this spurious warning, as shown in the code below:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr, *tmp;//I start with two pointers
    ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
//  ptr[0] = 10; // Move this to AFTER non-NULL check to avoid C6011...
    if (ptr != NULL)//make sure ptr is not null.
    {
        ptr[0] = 10; // ... moved to here!
        tmp = realloc(ptr, 5 * sizeof(int));//expand tmp up to 5
        if (tmp != NULL)//make sure it went well.
        {
            ptr = tmp;
        //  ptr[1] = 20;
            tmp[1] = 20; // This 'trivial' change silences the C6200
        //  (ptr = tmp)[1] = 20; // ... or you can use this in place of the above two lines!
        }
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a `#pragma warning(suppress:6200)` line immediately before the `ptr[1] = 20;` – this will disable that warning 'temporarily' and *only* for the next line, [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-160):

> `suppress`    Pushes the current state of the pragma on the
> stack, disables the specified warning for the next line, and then pops
> the warning stack so that the pragma state is reset.